# FluentValidation.AspNetCore is not working in Web API project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, fluentvalidation

I am using nuget package `FluentValidation.AspNetCore 11.0.1`. I want to validate my model based on a condition for my endpoint. Added required code blocks as per the Fluent validation documentation, but still, my validation does not work.

I want to return a validation error when my model property contains letter "a" as in my validator class. Please check the below code blocks added to my project for validation.

**Validator class**

```
public class TestModelValidate : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestModelValidate()
    {
        RuleFor(t => t.Summary.ToString()).NotEmpty().NotNull().When(x => x.Summary.Contains("a")).WithMessage("Cannot be null");

    }

}
```

**Startup class**

Added below code block to `ConfigureServices()` method in Startup class.

```
 services.AddControllers().AddFluentValidation(fvc => fvc.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<TestModelValidate>());
```

**Model class**

```
public class TestModel
{
   public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller class**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Test(TestModel model)
 {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
     {
          return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState);
     }

     return Ok("SUCCESS");
 }
```

I am passing following JSON object to the endpoint using Postman.

```
{
  "summary": "a"
}
```

Actual Result - `SUCCESS`

Expected Result - `Validation Error`

Appreciate, your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `ModelState.IsValid` we can try to set `ApiBehaviorOptions.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` be `true`.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
```

I think you can try to use `Must` with the condition `!x.Contains("a")` to judge your logic.

```
public class TestModelValidate : AbstractValidator<TestModel>
{
    public TestModelValidate()
    {
        RuleFor(t => t.Summary).NotEmpty().NotNull().WithMessage("Cannot be null")
                               .Must(x => !x.Contains("a")).WithMessage("Can't contain a");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution with `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true` doesn't works.

I'm using .NET 6 and `FluentValidation.AspNetCore 11.3.0` then I need to inject using `AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining` before registering controllers with `builder.Services.AddControllers();`

Example:

```
{...}
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<AddProductCommandValidator>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
{...}
```