# Fluent Validation failed to validate in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API, I am implementing Fluent Validation.

I have this model:

model:

```
public class Employee
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Dto:

```
public class EmployeeCreateDto
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

After that I did the validation here, using fluent validation:

```
public class EmployeeCreateDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<EmployeeCreateDto>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public EmployeeCreateDtoValidator(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public EmployeeCreateDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("First Name field is required. ERROR!")
            .NotNull().WithMessage("First Name cannot be null");

        RuleFor(user => user.LastName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessageLast Name cannot be null");

        RuleFor(user => user.RegistrationNumber)
            .Must(BeUniqueRegistrationNumber).WithMessage("The specified Registration Number already exists.")
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Registration Number field is required. ERROR!")
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Registration Number cannot be null")
    }
    private bool BeUniqueRegistrationtNumber(string name)
    {
        if (_dbContext.Employees.SingleOrDefault(x => x.RegistrationNumber.ToLower() == name.ToLower()) == null) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

The mapping to the Dto is done here:

```
public class MapperProfile: Profile
{
    public MapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<EmployeeCreateDto, Employee>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Employee, AllEmployeeListDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<BankUserCreateDto, BankUser>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

EmployeeService:

```
public async Task<Response<AllEmployeeListDto>> CreateEmployeeAsyncEmployeeCreateDto model)
{
    var existingEmployee = await _dbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.RegistrationNumber == model.RegistrationNumber);
    var response = new Response<AllEmployeeListDto>();
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        if (existingEmployee == null)
        {
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var employee = _mapper.Map<Employee>(model);

                await _unitOfWork.Employees.InsertAsync(employee);
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                response.Successful = true;
                response.Data = _mapper.Map<AllEmployeeListDto>(employee);
                response.Message = "Employee Created Successfully!";
                transaction.Complete();
                return response;
            }
        }
        else
        {

            transaction.Dispose();
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            response.Successful = false;
            response.Message = "Registration failed. Please try again";
            return response;
        }
        return response;
    };
}
```

AutoMapper Configuration:

```
public static class AutoMapperServiceExtension
{
    public static void ConfigureAutoMappers(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MapperProfile));
    }
}
```

The dependency Injection is also done.

```
public static class DIServiceExtension
{
    public static void AddDependencyInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Service Injections Here -- Employee
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeService, EmployeeService>();
        //services.AddScoped<IHttpClientService, HttpClientService>();
        // Add Repository Injections Here
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

        // Add Fluent Validator Injections Here
        // Employee Validator
        services.AddTransient<IValidator<EmployeeCreateDto>, EmployeeCreateDtoValidator>();
    }
}
```

Finally, I have the Program.cs

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;
var environment = builder.Environment;

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(options =>
                {
                    // Validate child properties and root collection elements
                    options.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    options.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                    options.AutomaticValidationEnabled = true;
                });

// Configure AutoMapper
builder.Services.ConfigureAutoMappers();
builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();
string? port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port))
{
    app.Urls.Add("http://*:" + port);
}
app.Run();
```

I think I have problems with Fluent Validation Configuration.
I am using ASP.NET Core-6.
If I enter the correct data, it successfully inserts everything into the database.

However, If I deliberately enter incorrect data, I I expect it to indicate with the help of Fluent Validation. But this is not happening. The data will only not get inserted.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: This is apparently my first time when I see using `FluentValidation` on the entity/dto level...

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72365332/fluentvalidation-aspnetcore-is-not-working-in-web-api-project) , try to use `ModelState.IsValid` .

Answer (score 0):

You have to put validation logic inside the same constructor.

try this.

```
public EmployeeCreateDtoValidator(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;

    RuleFor(user => user.FirstName)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("First Name field is required. ERROR!")
        .NotNull().WithMessage("First Name cannot be null");

    RuleFor(user => user.LastName)
        .NotEmpty().WithMessageLast Name cannot be null");

    RuleFor(user => user.RegistrationNumber)
        .Must(BeUniqueRegistrationNumber).WithMessage("The specified Registration Number already exists.")
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Registration Number field is required. ERROR!")
        .NotNull().WithMessage("Registration Number cannot be null")
}
```

Comment: Still not working. I suspect it may have to do with  Program.cs     What else do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```html
Builder.Services.AddControllers()
                .AddFluentValidation(options =>
                {
                    // Validate child properties and root collection elements
                    options.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true;
                    options.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
                    options.AutomaticValidationEnabled = true;
                });
```

And try this in your program file add

```html
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<YourValidtor>();
```

Then in your constructor inject IValidator validator.
Then in your action

```html
 ValidationResult result = await _validator.ValidateAsync(city);
            if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                result.AddToModelState(this.ModelState);
                
                return BadRequest(result);
            }
```

Hope this will help